# OAuth login with Laravel 10 and VueJS 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to use OAuth login for discord (https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#oauth2) for my website in previouse version I was using blade instead of Vue so I was using socialite and it was easy but now that I'm suing Vue I have no idea how can I generate and redirect user to discord login page and then get data in callback.

I tried socialite like this:

web.php

```
Route::get('/auth/discord', function () {
    return Socialite::driver('discord')->redirect();
});
Route::get('/auth/discord/callback', function () {
    $user = Socialite::driver('discord')->user();
    dd($user);
});
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <button @click="loginWithDiscord">Login with Discord</button>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  methods: {
    loginWithDiscord() {
      axios.get('/auth/discord').then(response => {
        window.location.href = response.data.redirect;
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But I'm getting this error in console:

```
Acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=34234&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Foauth%2Fcallback&scope=identify+email&response_type=code&state=Sadasdaa21=none' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/auth') from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-xsrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with OAuth, you need to add an exception to the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

```php
// app/Http/Middlewares/VerifyCsrfToken.php
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        '/auth/discord/callback',
    ];
}
```

This is done because whenever you hit your `auth/discord` endpoint, you will get redirected to `discord.com` and then `discord.com` will redirect back to `auth/discord/callback` without a valid CSRF token.

There is no way for an external site like `discord.com` to know a valid CSRF token for your application (that is the whole point), so you add an exception for that one endpoint.

---

The error also seems to indicate discord does not want you to send a `x-xsrf-token` header in the request. Perhaps you have configured axios to globally add this header? If so, you should delete it from this request.

```js
axios.get('/auth/discord', {
        transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
            delete headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN']; // or ['x-xsrf-token'], use console.log(headers.common) to see what's the key.
            return data;
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        window.location.href = response.data.redirect;
    });
```

Use your browser dev tools (or something like postman) to inspect the request you make to discord.com and make sure it does not have the x-xsrf-token header.

Comment: nope didn't work , still have the same error :(

Comment: I've added another possible solution below.

Comment: thanks but still not working :(( , I have this datas in header , Content-Type: null , X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest" and X-XSRF-TOKEN , it seems delete doesn't work or problem is something else

Comment: You have to delete that X-XSRF-TOKEN header

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by changing the "auth/discord" function to this:

```
return Socialite::with('discord')->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
```

the reason of the problem was without "getTargetUrl()" it was returing html codes instead of actual url